# What do we need to use in place of wear api in Android?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Android Wearable.API is deprecated ? so what do we need to use to build the api client.

My current code is

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

//From this the Wearable.API is deprecated.

I have gone through this link
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Wearable#getDataClient(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable.WearableOptions)

Here they have asked to change it to data client and message client.

So can anyone help me with some kind of example exactly how to do it ?
Thanks and Regards,

Update :
  Is the following correct way ?

```
 .addApi(Wearable.getDataClient(MainActivity.this).getApi())
.addApi(Wearable.getMessageClient(MainActivity.this).getApi())
```

If so then what is the use of interfaces of onMessageReceive() and onDataChange(). I mean I am already implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Google documentation here on migrating from the GoogleApiClient to objects based on the GoogleApi class.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/migrate-to-googleapi

Comment: So which object do I need to use to connect with my wear ?

Comment: Even in the example provided by them on github, they are still using GoogleApiClient to connect in service written for wear, and it has not been updated since two years.

Comment: Right - my understanding is as per the docs, as the example here shows:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DataLayer/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/datalayer/MainActivity.java

Comment: Do see what you mean about the service layer example though, that is still using the GoogleApiClient.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DataLayer/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/datalayer/DataLayerListenerService.java

Comment: Please see line number 53, now I need to manually connect my phone to wear app and start an activity, they have done it from wear to phone, I need to do it other way, connect from handheld to wear,and it is deprecated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/migrate-to-googleapi this doc link is broken also the github sample project